# Installing bumblebee on Freya

Tags: software-installation, graphic-drivers, bumblebee

I'm using Elementary OS Freya with UEFI mode. My laptop has two graphic cards (Intel 4400 and nVidia 860 GTX) and it is getting very hot after using about 30-60 minutes.

I tried to install bumblebee but every way I tried (like https://gist.github.com/jorgemario/96b18938090d2bd36405) the nVidia module was not installed correctly and said:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module bbswitch not found.
[  924.996622] [ERROR]Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
[  924.996656] [WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
[  924.997915] [ERROR]Module 'nvidia' is not found.
```

**Edit:**

One thing that i should mention is if [Luís's](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28/installing-bumblebee-on-freya#69) answer not working properly try to disable secure boot and UEFI from bios setting.

Comment: It would be great to add some information about your "some ways" of installing bumblebee so we can determine what you already tried, what went wrong and how we can get things right.

Comment: @emik i added one of my ways

Comment: 0.3.1 uses 15.04 as a kernel base, if you are looking for a place to start, and DOOM is looking for an answer and can test.

Comment: I have problem with install bumblebee. When I type `sudo apt-get install bumblebee nvidia-355` it tells me that it can't find that package. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 23/04/2016 UPDATE

**PLEASE REFER TO MY OTHER ANSWER**

### 11/09/15 UPDATE

**DON'T FOLLOW THESE INSTRUCTIONS. THEY ARE NOT NEEDED ANYMORE BECAUSE OF THE RECENT UPDATE OF THE GRAPHICAL STACK THAT OCURRED ON ELEMENTARY FREYA**

This is how I managed to install bumblebee and the nvidia driver in elementary OS. Unfortunately, I am unable to install any version higher than nvidia-331. Every attempt to install nvidia official drivers or xorg-edgers drivers or any other driver different from the 331 ended up with no login screen.

I was helped by the fact that I installed elementary OS on a Btrfs partition. I would strongly encourage everyone to do that before trying to mess with the graphics driver. The funny thing is that I have done several installations of the driver in Ubuntu machines before, for some reason it is a lot harder to do it on elementary OS. This is a nice operating system, it definitely deserves a try, but it can be a little rough at the edges at this point. I also plan to update in here for the other modifications I needed to do to the system.

**So only follow this instructions if you can afford losing everything on you machine, do it for your own risk, ok?**

If you decide to install elementary OS on a BTRFS partition, go and do your first backup using [Timemshift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html). Then learn how to use the app.

### Install bumblebee stable ppa

For some reason the bumblebee package on the repos do not work properly, the deamon keeps turning off. Also, the xorg-edgers ppa is incompatible with the modified version of lighdm from elementary OS and, even though, the installation can be done succesfully, you will end up stuck on a black screen in the first reboot after the installation.

The solution I found is to use this old ppa. I know, this is not perfect, but this was the only way to get bumblebee to work in my machine, and maybe this is also your case:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee nvidia-331primus
```

Then you have to make sure the bumblebee.conf is properly set:

```
sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

and add the modify as follows ( [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04) ):

```
[bumblebee] section: after "Driver=" insert "nvidia"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "KernelDriver=" insert "nvidia-XXX"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "LibraryPath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX, /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-XXX"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "XorgModulePath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
```

Where XXX is the nvidia driver you have installed, in the example:  nvidia-331

In my case, a simple  `sudo service bumblebeed restart` did the job, but you may need to restart.

Comment: I'm using nvidia-352 on elementary OS through xorg-edgers

Comment: Where can I find the updated instructions?

Comment: I can't provide you with updated instructions because after the last Freya version the graphics stack started working perfectly in my three setups... Sorry .

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS AN UPDATE FROM MY PREVIOUS ANSWER, SINCE A LOT HAVE CHANGED IN ELEMENTARY FREYA**

*Note that this answer uses ppas, which isn't advisable in a elementaryOS set up. However, to my knowledge, there is not an alternative way to do this. Thus, the instructions.*

This is how I managed to install bumblebee and the nvidia driver in elementary OS. Unfortunately, I am unable to properly install any version higher than nvidia-355. Every attempt to install nvidia official drivers or xorg-edgers drivers or any other driver different from the 355 ended up with black screen.

I was helped by the fact that I installed [Timeshift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) in my machine. I would strongly encourage everyone to do that before trying to mess with the graphics driver. The funny thing is that I have done several installations of the driver in Ubuntu machines before, for some reason it is a lot harder to do it on elementary OS.

**Only follow this instructions if you can afford losing everything in you machine, do it for your own risk, ok?**

Run your first backup using [Timemshift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html).

### Install opengl stable ppa & the graphics-drivers ppa

For some reason the bumblebee package on the repos do not work properly, the deamon keeps turning off. There is no need to install xorg-edgers ppa anymore.

The solution I found is to use the opengl+graphics-drivers stable ppas.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee nvidia-355
```

Then you have to make sure the bumblebee.conf is properly set:

```
sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

and add the modify as follows ( [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04) ):

```
[bumblebee] section: after "Driver=" insert "nvidia"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "KernelDriver=" insert "nvidia-XXX"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "LibraryPath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX, /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-XXX"
[nvidia-driver] section: after "XorgModulePath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
```

Where XXX is the nvidia driver you have installed, in the example:  nvidia-355

In my case, a simple  `sudo service bumblebeed restart` did the job, but you may need to restart.

If anyone managed to install bumblebee with later drivers, please report how you did it in the comments and I may update this answer. It seems that gala won't work with later version in my tests.