# Bumblebee - Module nvidia is not found

Tags: release-freya, bumblebee

I have Freya alongside with Windows 8 on UEFI mode. Recently I installed bumblebee on my Freya, But when I want to run `optirun` command it says :

```
module 'nvidia' is not found
```

I also read this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28/installing-bumblebee-on-freya).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is secure boot, it didn't allow bumblebee to install nvidia.

- Try to uninstall bumblebee

  `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
  sudo apt-get purge bumblebee`
- Turn of secure boot from your bios setting
- Install bumblebee agian and it will work properly