# Why heated notebook?

Tags: temperature

Why is my notebook very hot? I installed the driver for Nvidia, but nothing changed. Ubuntu has a temperature of 40-50C with the driver and 70-80C without the driver. Terminal:

```
sergey@sergey-Aspire-5750G:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +82.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +82.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +81.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: might be driver problem, have you tried removing drivers?

Comment: yes, I installed different driver. installed and removed it.

Comment: have you tried reboot?

Comment: Is it dual boot? The temperature problem is with __only__ elementary OS?

Comment: yes, eOS only..

Comment: It looks like a driver issue, try updating the driver to the latest version.

Comment: This question might be helpful to you: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/how-to-optimise-elementary-os-for-maximal-battery-life-time-on-laptops/

Comment: Does your card support Optirun? Are you using it? I have the same problem.

Comment: @codehitman yes, I have it. but I don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then we are going to install some packages that work really well with this issues. But first we need to remove laptop-mode-tools (if you didn't install it just go to the next step):

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Now, we have to install TLP:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

And also install thermald:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

Finally, reboot your system and you are done!

**Note**: I don't know what driver you've installed. If this doesn't work, the easy way to solve it would be reinstalling elementary OS and then installing again TLP and thermald.

---

---

[TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

[Thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues)

Comment: what temperature is considered normal?

Comment: For example, in a warm day with light use (just using the internet or writing a mail) the fan shouldn't spin really fast.

Comment: no, what temperature? I have 15C in the room and -1C outside :)

Comment: Men it depends on your laptop. But I'd consider 50-60 ºC a normal temperature. The lower the better, of course.

Comment: @Ravan I didn't write Sudo. I don't know where you found that...

Comment: see my edit revision http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/posts/2876/revisions

Comment: I am editing post to retract my DV :)

Comment: I am getting the same problem, but even after following all of your steps, my processor is still overheating. Forcing the Nvidia driver to use Power Saving Mode (Intel graphics) is the only way to cool it down. Any ideas? I have the dreaded Optirun technology.

Comment: @codehitman. It's the graphic card what's overheating your laptop. I've had the same problem in the past. You should try with [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation). 

Depending on your videocard you may want to disable it as well (some Nvidia cards are worse than Intel 4000 Graphics). You can do it by blacklisting the card using bbswitch. Just follow that guide in the link, there you have everything.  
  
If you are not using Ubuntu, then [look here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

Comment: @Maccer That's alright, I found a driver that works for me. Please see my answer below. Also, I have used Bumblebee in the past, but using Nvidia is somehow better. The whole process of installing bumblebee caused me trouble a couple of times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to note here is that if you are using Nvidia Graphics card with Optimus Technology and you are running official drivers. If you go to Nvidia X Server Settings, under PRIME profiles, you can select the Power Saving Mode which disables your Nvidia card and uses the motherboard's graphic card instead. This is essentially what Bumblebee does (kind of). This should also prolong your battery life. One thing to be mindful of here is that this could disable the graphics port connected to the card. For my laptop, this was the HDMI port; thankfully, the mini-display port is connected to the Intel Graphics card.