# NVIDIA GPUs on elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, bumblebee

I have recently installed **Elementary OS *FREYA***, And I am facing a huge problems with installing *graphics drivers* for NVIDIA for my config (see below.)

I have tried to follow the information as found on internet including:

1. [Nvidia Optimux with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

This resulted in my computer-fan running **wild** and my laptop shutting down with no information.

*I reinstalled OS* and after that I found the page [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28/installing-bumblebee-on-freya) which is now obselete solution as per the author himself.

I am trying to use the page [Bumblebee on UBUNTU WIKI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee), for installation but I cannot find the packages **"virtualgl*"** which are required by *Bumblebee*. I found the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04#comment834878_549916), which suggests installing **xorg-edgers ppa** which, I am not sure as you read the [homepage](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Can anyone provide me with a solution for installing graphics drivers for NVIDIA with **FREYA**

**UPDATE (NOT DUPLICATE)**

The solution as suggested in [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28/installing-bumblebee-on-freya) is similar to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04). This did not work for me because, this resulted in my computer-fan running **wild** and my laptop shutting down with no information.

```
CONFIG:
XPS L702X - i7-2670QM
XPS 72x BTS: 2nd generation Intel Core i7 - 267QM proc 2.20 GHz with Turbo
Display: 17.3in HD + WLED True-Life (1600 x 900) with 2.0 Mega Pixel Integrated
RAM Memory: 8GB
Graphics: 1GB NVIDIA GeForce GT 550M Graphics Card
```

Comment: ????? the ans to the problem that not valid !!!!!

Comment: DOOM, the current answer there not being valid is a separate, but notable problem. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate and place a bounty for a new answer on the original question.

Comment: I have the EXACT config as you. However, I was able to simply install the drivers from the Additional Drivers tab in 'Software & Updates' window. However, it still causes my fan to bezerk. I too am trying to install Bumblebee now.

Comment: The computer fan running wild indicates overheating because it shutdown